# ANT - Can't deploy Custom fields on Standard object

Tags: migration-tool

Is it possible to deploy Custom field on standard object via. ANT. I have checked it multiple time with following conclusion:
1. We can deploy Custom Field on Standard object via. Eclipse but not by ANT - Checked
2. We can deploy Custom Field on Custom Object via. ANT & Eclipse both - Checked

Can anyone confirm this?

---

Rechecked after comment by Sebastian and Himanshu. Still getting the same error:

### My Package.xml file is:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account.CATCTI__CAT_Age__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>`

---

Target is:

```
`<!-- Deploy the unpackaged set of metadata retrieved with retrieveUnpackaged and run tests in this organization's namespace only-->
<target name="deployUnpackaged">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="retrieveUnpackaged" rollbackOnError="true"/>
</target>`
```

---

Error received is: 
1.  objects/Account.object (Account.CAT_Age__c) -- Error: Not in package.xml

Comment: can you post your package.xml

Comment: I can guarantee it is possible to do it. Maybe you're doing something wrong. As requested, please post your package.xml.

Comment: Added more information & checked again. Still same issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure this is your package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account.FieldName__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: I have tried it many times on that day too. But it didn't work for me...
However, It is working now. I am accepting this answer.